# Full width website appearing differently because of width in pixels

Tags: html, css

I am creating a [full width website](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/bankalhabib/#). The website appears full width on my computer but when I check it on other computers, the website appears to have free space on both left and right.

How can I make this website full width?

```
.wrapper_boxed {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

One solution that I have read is I redevelop using percentage width.

Comment: If you want the website to be _100% of the width of the screen_, with no free space, then what is your opposition to using a width of _100%_?

Comment: Using pixels depends on monitor resolution ! Perhaps it looks 100% on your browser because of that. You should definitively use percent ratios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your main container :-

```
.wrapper_boxed {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

You will probably need to go through the elements within `wrapper boxed` to change any width pixel values to percentages.

Answer (score 1):

Percentage is definitely the easiest way, if you post some code we can look at uaing what you have and extending divs to keep the design and essentially stretch the sides. However anyone would just use:

```
width: 100%;
```